# cufon text displayed incorrectly

Tags: css, cufon

My font titles with cufon are cut on top and moved up, any ideea?
Maybe it's a css problem, I don't know, but I could not figure out.

http://www.quotestemple.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 3 pixel margin to the top of the `h3` elements:

```
h3 {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #281c17;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin: 3px 0 27px 0;
}
```

Comment: I have added the 10px margin and now the font is not cut anymore, but it's still up, I did not uploaded yet the website so you can see.

Comment: How do you mean 'it's still up'?

Comment: Try with Explorer, in chrome is ok. It is moved up. The number is in a position and the text after the number is up a few pixels.

Comment: I have uploaded the site with the changes, if you have IE 8,9 or 10, you can see the problem...

Comment: Have you tried anything to fix the problem? Try adding a negative margin to the `<span>` containing the number.